# Can I split my code into header and cpp files at the end of development?

Tags: c++, linker, visual-studio-2019, header-files

I am coding a minesweeper game and I am currently splitting declarations and code between header and cpp files like you're supposed to, however, this is making it kind of convoluted to keep track of everything.

I know this is against best practices, but could I just declare and code everything on cpp files and then split them up into their respective files at the end? Would this mess up anything inside Visual Studio 2019? I feel like it shouldnt but ive had linker problems with VS code in the past and I havent been able to fix them (one of the reasons why I use visual studio for cpp now) so I just want to make sure before I do something thats going to bite me later on.

Any insight is appreciated. I know its a lazy way to cope with the problem but Im just trying to get this done quickly.

Comment: Don't tag a C++ question with C too unless you are particularly fond of downvotes.

Comment: If there are no header files and only `.cpp` files, it's going to be pretty difficult for the different `.cpp` files to be on the same page. Copy-pasting the same class definition into multiple `.cpp` files, manually, always ends in tears. Header files exist for a very good reason, and not just for "best practice' (whatever that means, since if ten C++ developers get asked what would be the best practice <X> then at least eleven different responses are guaranteed to come back).

Comment: The thing that would give you linker issues would be failing to implement a function or implementing it more than once.    Aside from that, putting everything in .CPP files and only then moving to .H files is no problem.  Except, you're going to find yourself needing to forward-declare functions even in your .CPP files.  This is the entire reason for .H files

Comment: Do you have a single file at the moment, or do you already have multiple files?  How many lines are in the single file (if that's what you have)?  If you've got your code well organized, the splitting process should not make things convoluted.  If you've not got your code well organized, splitting might well make things worse before it makes them better.

Comment: If the reply helped , you can mark it as answer. It will help people  who have the same problem. Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring and coding everything on cpp files will cause error `lnk2005`. Putting it all in the header file won't cause the error, although this is also against best practices. But it all depends on personal writing style.In addition, code should be easier for others to read and understand. And It's a good choice to follow experienced people's coding style.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing that prevents you from having one monolithic .cpp. However, those of us with experience will probably tell you that's a mistake.

One of the cool things about C++ is that it encourages you to organize your code. It encourages you to think about how things are related, and to group like things together.

This shouldn't be convoluted. The header files contain declarations. The cpp files contain implementations. You name them to match. IOSystem.h and IOSystem.cpp go together.